# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi connection

Tags: 14.04

How can I download the driver from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817 and install it to get the internet working? I don't have wifi, how can I install this drive to be able to connect to wifi?

Comment: Your Ethernet connection should already be supported in the Linux kernel shipped with Ubuntu. The e1000e driver ships by default in 14.04. What Ethernet device do you have which requires this driver?

Comment: @popey The OP is in a XY trap. The OP doesn't even know what Ethernet device, if any, they have. And instead of testing a live session with a current Ubuntu like I suggested elsewhere, they insist in doing dumb things.